# Get callback in broadcast receiver when user start an activity like walking or running

Tags: android, google-fit

Is there a way to capture the event when a user starts walking or running with Google Fit SDK?

I was running a continuous background service to keep track if the user is running or walking, but it's battery consuming.

Google Fit SDK documentation mentions start and end session callbacks, but I don't understand how to register the callback for running or walking events.

Comment: use TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT instead of TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

set data type

```
DataReadRequest   readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT,
                            DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
                    .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
```

**get walking and running data**

```
if (dp.getValue(field1.get(0)).asActivity()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("walking")) {
                    walkingTime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dp.getValue(
                            field1.get(1)).asInt());

                    Log.e("walking", walkingTime + "");
                }

 if (dp.getValue(field1.get(0)).asActivity()
                        .contains("running")) {
                    runningTime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dp
                            .getValue(field1.get(1)).asInt());

                    Log.e("running", runningTime + "");
                }
```

Comment: this is after part , actually, i want to capture event when user change or start activity

Comment: use ActivityRecognition api, but this api use to much battery.

Comment: again ActivityRecognition also not event based .

Comment: ActivityRecognition is event based, its automatically triggered when user start activity else get STILL